# How to edit Motion Blur through script in Unity Engine

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-development

I have been trying to use motion blur in my project available in the post-processing volume. But there is little to no documentation on how to access the post-processing properties in a script.

What I basically want to do is, give the player an option to enable or disable the motion blur through a button.

Answer (score 0):

Can you give a bit more detail on your set up for post processing? It can vary depending on the render pipeline you are using I think. For instance, with URP you can have all of your post processing effects as components of an empty object, pretty straight forward to turn on and off.

Comment: I am using the standard default render pipeline, not URP or HDRP. I just want to enable and disable the motion blur effect through a script.

Comment: If you set up your post-process such as in this tutorial: https://forum.unity.com/threads/post-processing-with-built-in-render-pipeline.921503/
you should be able to turn on and off each effect as components from script, I think. Just create a script with a public GameObject, drag the empty object containing your post-processing set up inside the script. Then in should be pretty straight forward with something like emptyGameObject.GetComponent<MotionBlur>().enabled = false; 
I'm not in front of my PC right now so I cannot test anything but let me know if it helped or not!

Comment: Setting the parameter on the post-process volume through script is not a straightforward job due to the protection levels. But after reading multiple documentation on post-processing I was able to find the solution.

`mbActive = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("motion blur");
ppv = GetComponent<PostProcessVolume>();
ppv.profile.TryGetSettings<MotionBlur>(out mb);
if(mbActive == 1)
{
    mb.enabled.Override(true);
}
else if(mbActive == 0)
{
    mb.enabled.Override(false);
}
`

Anyways, thanks for your help!